# How can I idiomatically replace a record/row with another record/row while maintaining the original ids and references?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, updates

I have an ActiveRecord object with 3 "has_many" relations/sub ActiveRecords.

My goal is to have "clones" that are able to modify their own version of the og_actions/og_objects/ob_stories for testing purposes, but also have the ability to push the data from the parent to all clones to overwrite any changes that were made.

My assumed method of doing this is to update those relationships with the data from another ActiveRecord, however, I don't want to change the IDs or the Foreign_key references when I copy over the data.

How do I do that in an idiomatic way?
Or perhaps should I just delete all records and create new ones with the old ids? If so whats the best way to do that?

Here is the code I'm currently using, and its not working:

```
class App < ActiveRecord::Base
...

belongs_to :user
  has_many :og_actions
  has_many :og_objects
  has_many :og_stories
  has_many :log_reports
  has_many :clones, class_name: "App", foreign_key: "parent_id"
...
def populate_clones
  self.clones.each do |c|
    p "updating ->"
    self.og_actions.each_with_index do | oa, ai |
    new_og_action = OgAction.create(oa.attributes.merge({app_id:c.id, id: c.og_actions[ai].id }))
      c.og_actions[ai] = new_og_action
    end
    self.og_objects.each_with_index do |oo, oi|
      new_og_object = OgObject.create(oo.attributes.merge({app_id:c.id, id: c.og_objects[oi].id }))
      c.og_objects[oi] = new_og_object
    end   
    self.og_stories.each_with_index do | s, si|
      new_og_story = OgStory.create(s.attributes.merge({app_id:c.id, id: c.og_stories[si].id }))
      s.story_variants.each do_with_index do |v, vi|
        new_variant = StoryVariant.create(v.attributes.merge({og_story_id:new_og_story.id, id:c.og_stories[si].story_variants[vi].id}))
        new_og_story.story_variants[vi] = new_variant
      end
      c.og_stories[si] = new_og_story
    end
    c.save
  end 
  p "end Update"
end
```

I've also tried using the replace function, as well as a simple assignment of c.og_objects = self.og_objects  nothing seems to be working properly.  It either creates a new record creating duplication, replaces all the references, so the parent ActiveRecord loses its reference, or gets a "duplicate id" error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is tricky. I keep thinking about more and more cases in which there could be issues. Anyway here is a start:

```
def sync_clones
  clones.each do |clone|
    # Destroy any og_actions for clone that are no longer in the parent app
    clone.og_actions.where.not(parent_id: og_actions.ids).destroy_all

    # Create or update a og_action clone for app clone
    og_actions.each do |og_action|
      clone_attributes = og_action.dup.attributes.except("id").merge(parent_id: og_action.id)
      existing = clone.og_actions.find_by(parent_id: og_action.id)
      if existing
        existing.update(clone_attributes)
      else
        clone.og_actions.build(clone_attributes)
      end
    end
    # ...
  end
end
```

This will update the clone faithfully and not create unnecessary records. It does require you to keep track of the parent og_action record. This is because you can't rely on `og_actions` index to identify the matching clone record (what would happen if you destroy one `og_action` or add one, or if the order is changed another way).

Comment: I want the clones to be able to modify their own version of the og_actions for testing purposes, but also have the ability to pull the data from parent to overwrite any changes they made.  Is that possible from this method?

Comment: I see. If you want to do something like that then you will have to rethink the data structure a bit. You could keep your clone method the way it is, but then create a field called parent_id where you will store the id of the OgAction you are cloning from. Then you will have to create an after_save callback for OgAction that syncs the data in all the cloned OgActions. If you would also have to include this functionality in App if you want App clones to sync with their parent. You can define the syncing method in a way that only syncs the attributes you want.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding. Can you put that in your answer?   I'm using parent_id as the foreign key for the clones relation.  I need to add the same thing to each of the other classes used and have a similar cloning mechanism in each class?

Comment: Hmm, couldn't I use replace but exclude the id and app_id from the replacement?

Comment: I updated my answer. I don't think replace will do what you hope. It will copy the records, but it will also give you the duplication that you are trying to avoid. What you really want to do is update records that already exist, create records that don't, and delete records that are destroyed in the parent App associations.

Comment: Great thanks!
A small follow up questions I'm trying to wrap my head around.
 Does this imply a new property called "parent_id" that exists in OgAction?

Comment: Yes it does. You need some reference there or you wont know which OgAction associated to the parent App should be compared in the cloned App's associated OgActions.

Comment: I'm getting the following error, when I try to build the children of stories.
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR:  null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (null, win_a_free_chips, 302792a62e3e410152e4f2715b5ad2d4, 1, null, null, 1).
: UPDATE "stories" SET "id" = $1, "app_id" = $2, "created_at" = $3, "updated_at" = $4 WHERE "stories"."id" = 3):
  app/models/app.rb:99:in `block (2 levels) in sync_clones'
Any ideas why the id might be null?

Comment: Yes for sure. Id is returned in the attributes method. You don't want it in any case. You can use the active suppory hash method `except` to remove it. `clone_attributes = og_action.dup.attributes.exept (:id).merge(parent_id: og_action.id)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97427/discussion-between-avik-and-jphager2).